# Mesh disappears in BGE

Tags: game-engine, 3d-view

I´m creating a FPS game, but an error is occurring when I start the game. My person is disappearing.

In the 3D View, everything appears normal.

[image: 3D view]

But in BGE, it disappears.

[image: BGE]

Note: I´m using 2 .blend files, with textures. I don´t know if it is related, but I need help.

I tried to Flip Direction, Recalculate UV, etc. but it doesn't work. Why?

Comment: Download File 1 [link](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/2059/)

Comment: Download File 2 [Link](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/2060/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found a video that explain my problem.[View video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IESuRHENml4)

The bug occurs because my object is out of vision camera, I think, but i´m not sure.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, my character does not appear because it was restricted for rendering (or invisible for rendering)

Bad configuration:

[image]

Bad result:

[image]

Good configuration:

[image]

Result:

[image]

The solution is "Restrict rendering"

[image]

Good Luck!